# Is there a xpath to get these values only

Tags: xslt, xsltforms

Can any one help me to get right Xpath for appropriate transformation through xslt??

As I am attempting to transform the input.xml using xslt through xpath `(document(input.xml)//track)` to get the desire output as noted below.

**input xml:** as noted below

```
    <mergingTracksBreakdownStructure>
    <track id="10">
      <mergedTrack id="10"/>
      <mergedTrack id="11"/>
      <mergedTrack id="12"/>
       <track id="13">
         <mergedTrack id="13"/>
         <mergedTrack id="14"/>
           <track id="15">
              <mergedTrack id="15"/>
               <mergedTrack id="16"/>
            </track>
        </track>
    </track>
    <track id="27">
      <mergedTrack id="27"/>
    </track>
    <track id="30">
    <mergedTrack id="30"/>
    </track>
    </mergingTracksBreakdownStructure>
```

**ouput xml needed:** as noted below

```
    <mergingTracksBreakdownStructure>
     <track id="10">
       <mergedTrack id="10"/>
       <mergedTrack id="11"/>
       <mergedTrack id="12"/>
    </track>
    <track id="13">
      <mergedTrack id="13"/>
      <mergedTrack id="14"/>
    </track>
    <track id="15">
      <mergedTrack id="15"/>
      <mergedTrack id="16"/>
    </track>
    <track id="27">
      <mergedTrack id="27"/>
    </track>
    <track id="30">
      <mergedTrack id="30"/>
    </track>
    </mergingTracksBreakdownStructure>
```

XSLT used for transormation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="output.xml" method="xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('input.xml')//track"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `xsl:result-document ` or the `document()` function?

Comment: sorry edited the xslt code line now, <xsl:result-document href="output.xml" method="xml"> Regarding need I want to transform input.xml as output.xml with some other templates as well. Thanks @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

The requested output can be achieved quite easily by applying the following stylesheet to the input XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/mergingTracksBreakdownStructure">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="track"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="track">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | mergedTrack"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="track"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```